# Is there a word for "didactic in a funny way"?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

There is this podcast I was listening to, in which the speaker recounts an experience at college quite hilariously but also teaches a great lesson (the lesson of sharing and the joy it brings) at the end of it. If I were to describe the podcast in one word, what would it be?

Here's a link to it :-)
https://themoth.org/storytellers/ashok-ramasubramanian

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't actually recommend using this word, but the first thing that came to my mind was "edutaining." It's related to the term "[edutainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_entertainment)" that was formed as a blend of "education"  and "entertainment." This term is not common, and it still sounds silly to me and probably lots of other people. Some people might also have a negative reaction to it as "not a real word" or "advertising/marketing"-type jargon.

Here's an example of a comment where somebody used the word *edutaining* with this meaning:

> I Loved BLOOD DIAMOND. Great story, very 'edutaining' (you're
>   entertained and you learn a little too!) —thetvaddict (http://www.thetvaddict.com/2007/02/07/live-blogging-lost-episode-7-season-3/)

I found this example via [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/edutaining); you can see some more examples there.